# Lowering the volume of a html audio in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I want to reduce the volume of an `<audio>` when the user clicks on an image.

---

HTML:

```
<div id="cloud">
<img name="jsVolumeButton"  src="images/cloud.png" width = "140px"/> </div>
<audio id="player" src="sounds/rain.MP3" autoplay loop></audio>
```

JS:

```
var myimgobj = document.images.jsVolumeButton.onclick();
var mysoundobj = document.sounds.player;
function onclick() {
 if(document.getElementById('player').volume === 0){
     document.getElementById('player').volume = 1;
 }else
    document.getElementById('player').volume -= 0.1; 
    return true;
}
```

As you can see, my knowledge of HTML/JS is very limited. I only did C++ so far, and just did some learning by doing, but I'm hitting a wall where I need to ask.

I want to click on the image and lower the volume by 0.1. If it reaches 0, I want it to play at full volume again. I think this should be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it: 
html:

```
<img name="jsVolumeButton"  src="images/cloud.png" width = "140px" onClick="onClickImage()"/> </div>
```

JS:

```
function onClickImage() {
  document.getElementById('player').volume -= 0.2; 
    if(document.getElementById('player').volume <= 0.1){
     document.getElementById('player').volume += 1;
 }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a simpler and more efficient solution than what you are trying to do.

Just use a html attribute `controls` like this:

```
<audio src="Your/src.mp3" controls></audio>
```

Notice the `controls` in the above code.
Cheers!

Comment: Not really since i wanted to avoid having the player ui.